# Multiple subscribe not working with enableProtocol:true

Tags: websocket, long-polling, atmosphere

I am using atmosphere jersey with redis broadcaster.
When I keep enableProtocol:true in javascript, the first subscribe request is successful.
But when I send next subscribe request I get Continuation Frame warning. I tested on Google chrome. I have attached the snapshot[image: here].

What could the issue be?

It works when I keep enableProtocol:false. But then onDisconnect is not called in long-polling.

After some observation I found that the X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0 in first request and in subsequent requests I get it as the tracking id of previous request.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by manually setting the tracking-id to 0 before each subscribe.

`$.atmosphere.uuid = 0`